# Why is my copy & paste column function not working in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MMUrhT-MdUIqOjQ0pB5XqXvOMlVpZKiNfJbjgC7K7oU/edit?usp=sharing)
I have a script to gather some data and format it. Eventually I want to copy column H & paste into F.

I recorded this step as a macro and as a standalone function, it works fine doing the copying.

But when I added this to the rest of the script, just that part will not run. The script stops just before the copy/paste. I don't understand what is wrong.

Individually this is the copy paste function:

```
function Copypaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESULT').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(0);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
```

This is the entire script with this copy paste code at the end:

```
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
function grabData() {
  const sheetIn = sS.getSheetByName('DATA')
  const sheetOut = sS.getSheetByName('RESULT')
  const range = 'A1:B'
  /* Grab all the data from columns A and B and filter it */
  const values = sheetIn.getRange(range).getValues().filter(n => n[0])
  /* Retrieve only the names if it containes 250p */
  /* In format [[a], [b], ...] */
  const parsedValues = values.map((arr) => {
    const [type, name] = arr
    if (type.toLowerCase().includes('250g')) {
      return name.split('\n')
    }
  })
    .filter(n => n)
    .flat()
    .map(n => [n])
  /* Add the values to the Desired Outcome Sheet */
  sheetOut
    .getRange(sheetOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1, parsedValues.length)
    .setValues(parsedValues)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "RESULT";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var meals = sheet.getRange(1, 1, LR);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: range: "+range.getA1Notation());
  var v = meals.getValues();

  var startrow = 1;
  var outputrange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, LR - startrow, 1);
  var output = []


  for (var i = startrow - 1; i < LR; i++) {
    var outputrow = []; output
    var Unit = v[i][0].substring(0, 1);
    var Name = v[i][0].substring(2);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Unit:"+Unit+,Name: "+Unit+");
    outputrow.push(Unit);
    outputrow.push(Name);
    output.push(outputrow);
    String
  }
  var outputrange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, LR - startrow + 1, 2);
  outputrange.setValues(output);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Result";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeb = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + lastRow);
  rangeb.trimWhitespace();
}
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESULT').activate();
  sh.getRange('G1').activate();
  sh.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY(A:B,"Select B, Sum(A) group by B")');

{  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESULT').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(0);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
};
};
```

logger.log()
[image]

Comment: Please provide this Logger.log(): `const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
function grabData() {
  const ish = sS.getSheetByName('DATA')
  const osh = sS.getSheetByName('RESULT')
  const range = 'A1:B'
  const vs = ish.getRange('A1:B' + ish.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(n => n[0])
  const parsedValues = vs.map((r) => {
    const [type, name] = r
    if (type.toLowerCase().includes('250g')) {
      return name.split('\n')
    }
  })
    .filter(n => n)
    .flat()
    .map(n => [n])
    Logger.log(parsedValues);`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I am quite new to scripting. :(

Comment: I want to see the Logger.log() of parsedValues. Please post it into your question

Comment: added it now as a screenshot

Comment: I think you're going to have to debug this yourself.

Comment: I cannot understand the relationship between "Individually this is the copy paste function:" and "This is the entire script with this copy paste code at the end:". Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: When I said individually, what I did was record that macro step of copy paste. And I ran just that code alone on the data to see if it works. Then I put that code to the end of the script I was building. There the macro would stop just before this copy paste code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a sample spreadsheet to test, but `TypeError: v[i][0].substring is not a function` means that you're calling `substring()` on something that is not a string. You can log the value of `v[i][0]` at that point to know for sure.

Maybe the cell has a numeric format or something else. According to the Apps Script [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) documentation: *"The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String, depending on the value of the cell."*.

Since the values in `v` seem to come only from a single column, a quick and dirty fix could be to just convert all the elements to strings, and then call substring on them. Something like this:

```
  var v = meals.getValues();
  vstring = v.map(function(v){return v.toString()})
```

The array `vstring` is now just a one-dimensional array with the values so you'll have to change that in your `for` loop as well:

```
  for (var i = startrow - 1; i < LR; i++) {
    var outputrow = []; output
    var Unit = vstring[i].substring(0, 1);
    var Name = vstring[i].substring(2);
    //etc
```

Comment: Sorry, here is the sample sheet. I want all of this to happen in RESULT tab.

Comment: I tested the code using your sample sheet and got a different error than the one in your screenshot. The error I got was that there were no results in the range filtered. The cause was a typo in the line `if (type.toLowerCase().includes('250g')) {`. It's filtering by the value `250g` and the sheet has `250p`. After I corrected it to `250p` the function ran correctly. The results page looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyNsD.png). Is that what you're looking for? Still, I recommend you apply what I mentioned in the answer to prevent the type error if you're using numeric values.